# How to add multiple wallpapers for choose in wallpaper picker to set on homescreen in aosp build

Tags: android, android-layout, operating-system, android-source

I have build AOSP v10 and build it sucessfully.
I want to add some wallpapers in the aosp to display in wallpaper picker to set wallpaper in home screen.
I have no idea about at which directory I have to add my wallpapers which I want to add in the AOSP to use as a choice for set on homescreen.

I have this [Source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r41:) on my device.

I want to add some wallpapers (Showing in the below picture ) which can be used by wallpaper picker to set on the home screen

[image: I want to put my wallpaper here to use easily to set on screen]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make a [mre] but a MINIMAL, with not too much code to easier identify the problem

Comment: I am sorry for that, But I have no idea which section is responsible for adding wallpapers in the wallpaper picker which is opened to set the wallpaper on home screen. The default wallpaper which set on the home screen in building the project is located in [directory](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r41:frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/) and the wallpaper picker is available in [Directory](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r41:packages/apps/). I have no idea about the code and where to add wallpapers.

Comment: Yes but if you, you try to find where it comes from, that can help yourself. At least to reduc it to specific components, and not your hole project

Comment: I have tried to find but I am unable to understand. I have found the app directory [wallpaper picker app](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r41:packages/apps/WallpaperPicker/) which(showing in the screenshot) is responsible for set wallpaper on home screen. I do not know what changes I do in this app or where I put my extra wallpapers which can be used by this wallpaper picker app. I have lack of knowledge about java and android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prepare your images

Create a square, thumbnail image (560x560px, not sure if it needs to be this size). This image will be shown on the bottom row of the wallpaper picker (See your screenshot in your question).

Your original image should have the same resolution as your screen. Give your image a file name, for example `wallpaper.png`. Then name your thumbnail the same file name plus `_small`, for example `wallpaper_small.png`.

2. Copy the images to `packages/apps/WallpaperPicker/res/drawable-nodpi/`. Create this directory if necessary
3. List the images in `packages/apps/WallpaperPicker/res/values-nodpi/wallpapers.xml`

This file looks like this on unmodified AOSP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 -->

<resources>
    <string-array name="wallpapers" translatable="false">
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Add `<item>` inside `<string-array>` tag. Each item should have the name of the wallpaper file name without extension. If you have multiple wallpapers, list them one by one. For example

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="wallpapers" translatable="false">
        <item>wallpaper1</item>
        <item>wallpaper2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. It works for me to add new wallpapers in AOSP v10.